# SuiteCloud IDE Validator Ignore List

Tags: eclipse, netsuite, suitescript

In the SuiteCloud Eclipse IDE for NetSuite, what is the *Ignore List* setting under *Preferences* > *NetSuite* > *Validation*? Is it a single file that behaves like, say, a *.gitignore*? Or is it an explicit list of files to ignore?

I suspect this setting is why Eclipse is always building libraries and other files I've explicitly told it not to in my NetSuite projects.

Can anyone provide some clarity on the usage of this field?

**Attempt 1**

I tried setting this preference to a single file with the following contents:

```
**/*.min.js
**/*.lib.js
**/docs/**
**/Third Party/**
**/node_modules/**
**/bower_components/**
**/*jquery*
**/*moment*
**/*lodash*
```

But that does not seem to work as expected. Files that should be caught by these regexes are still validated. One of them in particular (docstrap.lib.js) crashes the entire IDE every single time when the SuiteScript validator encounters it.

**Attempt 2**

I tried to put a similar string of regexes directly into the field itself:

```
**/*.min.js,**/*.lib.js,**/docs/**,...
```

but this just yields an error directly in the dialog itself: *Value must be an existing file*

**Attempt 3**

Created a new SuiteScript project with only blanket.min.js in the project root. Added an ignore file with the following contents:

```
/blanket.min.js
./blanket.min.js
*blanket.min.js
blanket.min.js
"blanket.min.js"
*blanket*
**/blanket*
*/blanket*
.\blanket.min.js
**\blanket*
*\blanket*
\blanket.min.js
\blanket*
.\blanket*
C:\Development\Projects\validator-test\blanket.min.js
C:/Development/Projects/validator-test/blanket.min.js
```

blanket.min.js *still* gets validated. Completely lost as to how this ignore file should be formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ignore list is used by the SuiteCloud IDE (IDE) to avoid having errors in the IDE for non-standard script ids in SuiteScript 1.0 APIs.
As an example...

```
nlapiLogRecord('customrecord_foo');
```

Since customrecord_foo is a non-standard record, it will be marked as an error by the IDE.
To tell the IDE to ignore customrecord_foo, the ignore list can be used.

It's a text file, with one script id per line.

```
customrecord_foo
customrecord_bar
```

The specified non-standard script ids in the ignore list file will not be flagged as an error by the IDE.

Comment: That is not at all what I thought that feature was for, and that is extremely disappointing. I suppose I can just permanently turn off the SuiteScript validator in all my projects. Thanks for the answer.